# Angular variable assign value if/else inside subscribe getting undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

here is my complete code function example:

```
public scan(formData: Object): Observable<any> {

let url = this.remoteUrl;


let result;
this.onlineService.isOnline$.subscribe( (isOnline) => {
  if (isOnline) {

    console.log('services is online connected');
    
    result = this
    ._http
    .post(url, formData, { headers: headers })
    .pipe(map((res: any) => {
      // console.log(res);

      let response = res;
      return response;
    }),
      catchError(error => {
        if (error.status === 401 || error.status === 403) {
          // handle error
        }
        return throwError(error);
      }));

  }else{

    console.log('services are offline');

    result = this.dbService.getByIndex('safety', 'code', formData['trafoStation']).subscribe( (location) => {
      return location;
    });

  }

});
console.log(result);

return result;
};
```

actually, I need to run two different services based on an internet connection if the connection is available then call server API otherwise store on offline ngx-indexed-db.

i have stored data both online and offline.

getting undefined in result.

Comment: Your reult will be displayed immedietly once the vaiable has got declared. The changes in your service will be available inside the `subscribe` method only. This is an asynchronus task.

Comment: can you please share to modify the above code ..? i didn't get your point

Comment: Your `console.log(result);` should be inside the subscribe because it is an asynchronus task.

Comment: I need `console.log(result);` outside of subscribe

Comment: @MuzafarAli Javascript is single threaded.At a time t1 your initialization `let result;` will happen.After a small time difference t1+delta you added the subscription for your online servece with `this.onlineService.isOnline$.subscribe( (isOnline) => {`.After that you tried to log your result. But the value in `result` will happens may be some other time when the service returns a value. The code block to be executed when the service returns a value must be added inside `subscribe`. Line after the subscribe will be executed almost the same time you declared the variable and subscription.

Comment: You means
`this.onlineService.isOnline$.subscribe( (isOnline) => {
  if (isOnline) {
    result = services

  }else{


    result = services;

  }
return result;
});
console.log(result);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result is undefined because it's an async operation: `this.onlineService.isOnline$` has not emmited yet, but you already have return result, thus the undefined.

Also, the way you combine your observables is not right. You should NOT create new observables (and subscribe to them) in a subscribe method. That lead to weird side effects and memory leaks down the line.

Here's my proposal to get your code to work. I used the switchMap operator to return either your apiCall or your store operation based on `isOnline$` value. [SwitchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) is used to combine a higher observable with an inner observable and flatten the stream. It will also interupt the current subscription each time isOnline$ emits:

```
private _handleServices(formData, isOnline: boolean): Observable<any> {
    console.log(`services are ${isOnline ? 'online': 'offline'}`);
    const url = this.remoteUrl;
    const apiCall$ = this._http.post(url, formData, { headers: headers })
      .pipe(
        catchError(error => {
          if (error.status === 401 || error.status === 403) {
            // handle error
          }
          return throwError(error);
        })
      );
   const store$ = this.dbService.getByIndex('safety', 'code', formData['trafoStation']);
   return (isOnline) ? apiCall$ : store$;
}

public scan(formData: Object): Observable<any> {
  return this.onlineService.isOnline$.pipe(
    switchMap((isOnline) => this._handleServices(formData, isOnline)),
    tap(res => console.log(res))
  );
};
```

Then, when you call your function in your component, you will call it like this:

```
this.scan(formData).subscribe(res => /* handle scan response */);
```